# Trick windows into thinking it just rebooted

Tags: c#, windows

We have an application that needs get from an Administrator account to another limited account and the other way around. Currently we are setting the auto logon in the registry, then reboot the machine. This takes up to 3 reboots as the machines are EWF enabled. Our customer support just cannot sit around and wait for the remote machines to reboot while there's an angry customer on the phone.

We have a windows service and a ui running on the machines (written in C#). Most of them are windows 7, but some are windows xp and windows 8.

I was wondering if anybody here knows a way to maybe trick windows into thinking it was just rebooted and auto log into an account. Anybody know of anything? I do know there are tricky ways to log into an account automatically from the login screen, but as far as I understand that's going to require writing a module to replace GINA in windows XP, and in windows vista and up, since GINA was replaced with a "Content Provider", writing a Content Provider or something, both of which seem overkill, but a possible future solution. Any ideas?

NOTE: We are not switching between accounts so that the application can run a process under that account, we are switching between accounts so real people have either administrative access or limited access to the computer. Hope that makes it a little more clear

Comment: You can log onto windows as a limited user and run any application as an administrator or as any other user.  Or vice versa I believe.  Would this solve your problem?  Why do you need the entire shell to be loaded as different users?

Comment: I know you can trick windows to automatically log on again when you log off, so you don't need a full reboot. And of course you can just execute code as somebody else. You won't be able to get around the EWF without a reboor, though.

Comment: We use ewfmgr -commitanddisable -live c: to turn off ewf, but we cannot do that as a limited user (although we can run processes as another user, which we do in some cases). We need to be able to login as administrator so the tech guys and customer service can remote in using our product and fix the machine and do things a limited user cannot do. They won't want to be typing commands into command prompt to do everything if you know what i mean

Comment: @PMF, thats exactly what i'm looking for, could you give me some more details?

Comment: First: If you start i.e a shell or an explorer as another user, you can run as many tasks as you wish as this user. Everything you start from that process inherits the rights of the calling process. For the automatic logon, I have to dig a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do this (Remote Desktop is usually your friend in these scenarios) but FWIW, killing the logonui.exe process and then calling `SendSAS` will work most of the time, though it is not reliable.  (Also, `SendSAS` will not work at all without first either registering the application as an accessibility app or changing the SAS system policy.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application that needs to run between other users and an administrator, you should be creating a launcher application. The launcher application should be using [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start your application. You can supply [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) arguments to `Process.Start()` so that you can run the application using [different credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username.aspx).

Comment: We do this already. The user account passwords are encrypted and change often, and a user account can only be logged in automatically, for security reasons. We just need automatically switch between users, and not for running processes as that user

Comment: @iedoc -- Try looking at [this SuperUser Question](http://superuser.com/questions/165490/is-there-a-quicker-way-to-switch-user-accounts-on-windows-7)

Comment: thanks for the link, i have already seen that though, and the link in the "correct" answer is just to log off. Logging off is easy enough, just logging back in automatically is the problem. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Here'some help. For Xp, there's a simple registry key that does it (search google for AutoLogon), for Win7, it's a bit more complex. See this topic: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows-7/99d4fe75-3f22-499b-85fc-c7a2c4f728af

I think we had something like this running somewhere, but it wasn't my task and the collegue is on vacation this week. Maybe the above link helps, i'll ask him otherwise.

Comment: Thanks PMF, but we already have automatic logon capability. It's just that we need to reboot the machine to actually log into the account. I was hoping there was a way to logoff an account then logon to another account, possibly by tricking windows into thinking it was just rebooted instead of an account just logging off. I've tried the explorer thing before, but that only opens a new explorer windows (probably under the credentials provided when running the process to start explorer)

Comment: What's the problem with the explorer window? Can't you fix the app from there? Actually I was quite sure the automatic logon would also work if you just loged off instead of rebooting. Did you try that?

Comment: ok i'm trying it now, that would be so nice if it worked. i'll post back in a couple minutes

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no luck. the application just logs off the user and sits...